# Unity3d Facebook SDK 6.2.2 Error

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

![Xcode screen][1]

XCode Error, how to fix this problem? FBSDKLoginKit present in library list. Maybe unity3d 5 doesn't support Facebook SDK 6.2.2 version?

> Ld
>   /Users/Arahis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ciwadoyxuyddvuagqxleasaxynhi/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/slotspanther
>   normal armv7
>       cd /Users/Arahis/Builds/Build1
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/Arahis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ciwadoyxuyddvuagqxleasaxynhi/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/Arahis/Builds/Build1 -L/Users/Arahis/Builds/Build1/Libraries -L/Users/Arahis/Builds/Build1/Libraries/Plugins/IOS -F/Users/Arahis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ciwadoyxuyddvuagqxleasaxynhi/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/Arahis/Builds/Build1 -filelist /Users/Arahis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ciwadoyxuyddvuagqxleasaxynhi/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/slotspanther.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/Arahis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ciwadoyxuyddvuagqxleasaxynhi/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/slotspanther-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt
>   -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework Security -framework Social -framework GameKit -framework Accounts
>   -framework CoreTelephony -framework MobileCoreServices -framework StoreKit -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework UIKit
>   -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -liconv.2 -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreLocation -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework iAd -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -weak_framework
>   AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreMotion
>   -liPhone-lib -lFlurry -lOneSignal -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework Bolts
>   /Users/Arahis/Builds/Build1/Libraries/Plugins/IOS/MobileAppTracker-3.9.1.a
>   -framework FBSDKCoreKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Arahis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ciwadoyxuyddvuagqxleasaxynhi/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/slotspanther_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/Arahis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-ciwadoyxuyddvuagqxleasaxynhi/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/slotspanther

ld: framework not found FBSDKLoginKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: is the FBSDKLoginKit visible in Xcode under the Frameworks folder, or at least under the Facebook folder?

Comment: Under the Frameworks folder, there is no facebook folder in project

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 7 the "Facebook SDK for Unity" will supports Unity 5 fully.

You can download 7.0.2, which is currently in beta at the bottom of this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads

Comment: When I add 7.0.2 version, I have this problem:
Uncaught exception: NSInvalidArgumentException: Read permissions are not permitted to be requested with publish or manage permissions.
I tried both login methods:
FB.LogInWithReadPermissions("email,public_profile,publish_actions,user_friends", AuthCallback);
FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions("email,public_profile,publish_actions,user_friends", AuthCallback);

Comment: that's a different question, but you need first only the read permission so you can login the user and then later the first time the user wants so share something then request the publish permissions. read also this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3